# How to create a dataframe from a complicated seperator combinations (from txt file)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I want to scrape the data from the avast website's [virus-update-history section](https://www.avast.com/virus-update-history). The Data is in the following format:

```
28.03.2018 - 180328-2
PwrSh:EncCmndTest-A [Trj]
25.03.2018 - 180325-0
ELF:Mirai-MR [Trj], MacOS:Miner-A [Trj], Android:SpyAgent-ZW [Trj], Android:SpyAgent-ZX [Trj]
```

For which my preferred output must be:

```
28.03.2018    PwrSh    EncCmndTest-A    [Trj]
25.03.2018    ELF      Mirai-MR         [Trj]
25.03.2018    MacOS    Miner-A          [Trj]
25.03.2018    Android  SpyAgent-ZW      [Trj]
25.03.2018    Android  SpyAgent-ZX      [Trj]
```

I am trying to use pandas pd.read_csv but I cannot seem to figure out the correct combinations of seperators and the exact loops for creating this dataframe.

Comment: Is it acceptable answer to first convert to CSV and *then* use pandas to read into dataframe or is there a requirement why this cannot be done?

Comment: The data format is not CSV. So read_csv can't do anything for you. You will need to convert first.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most eloquent solution, but this works for your example, assuming that each date entry always has three associated pieces of information.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

raw = ['28.03.2018 - 180328-2',
'PwrSh:EncCmndTest-A [Trj]',
'25.03.2018 - 180325-0',
'ELF:Mirai-MR [Trj], MacOS:Miner-A [Trj], Android:SpyAgent-ZW [Trj], Android:SpyAgent-ZX [Trj]']

out = []

with open('converted.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    for idx, i in enumerate(raw):
        if i[0].isdigit():
            date = i.split(' - ')[0]
        else:
            info = [j for j in re.split(r',| |:', i) if j!='']
            for i in range(int(len(info)/3)):
                myfile.write(date + ',' + ','.join(info[3*i:3*(i+1)]) + '\n')

df = pd.read_csv('converted.csv', header=None)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            0        1              2      3
0  28.03.2018    PwrSh  EncCmndTest-A  [Trj]
1  25.03.2018      ELF       Mirai-MR  [Trj]
2  25.03.2018    MacOS        Miner-A  [Trj]
3  25.03.2018  Android    SpyAgent-ZW  [Trj]
4  25.03.2018  Android    SpyAgent-ZX  [Trj]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful, it gets be closer to my goal.

in your solution raw = [ ] consists of the dates being enclosed in single quotes. My dataset does not. This is only first couple of lines from thousands of lines of data which I possess in a txt file. I tried importing the file's contents in the raw vairable but the loop throws errors because of the formatting differences.

Comment: You may need to ensure they are all converted to strings, and you can leverage `replace` or `re.sub` to further refine the data set prior to reformatting them into a csv.